# curl: 301 moved pernamently, browser see page

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-301

I have problem with curl

```
curl http://store.ebizmarts.com/media/feeds/Ebizmarts_MageMonkey.xml
```

this or any other url return 301. The same urls in browsers are working fine.

php5.5

```
curl --version
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

I don't know where should I looking for resolve.

Thanks for time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want follow the redirect, you need to supply the `-L` options to curl.

```
curl -L http://store.ebizmarts.com/media/feeds/Ebizmarts_MageMonkey.xml
```

In php:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: is passible to change sth in php.ini or other config file, not in php code?

Comment: no, curl does not follow so-called redirects by default. if you want do follows http redirect you need to tell curl that you want to do it.